# How to count records from a list of values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a list of products and I would like to search into the order's table and count how many batch had been produced.

How can I achieve that?
I'm working with this SQL instruction and I found all the batches of the products in the product's list. How can I count them, grouping by article name?

```
Select articlename, articleqnty, articleuom from orders
where articlename in (product1, product2, product3, etc...)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle group/count query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8492347/oracle-group-count-query)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sum the `articleqnty` to get a total then:

```
Select articlename,
       SUM( articleqnty ) AS total_qnty
from orders
where articlename in (product1, product2, product3, etc...)
group by articlename;
```

or, if you just want a count of the rows then:

```
Select articlename,
       COUNT(1) as num_articles
from orders
where articlename in (product1, product2, product3, etc...)
group by articlename;
```

If you want something else then you will need to edit your question with a clarification.